# Javascript garbage collection of typed arrays in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, garbage-collection

Please consider the following javascript. I would have thought that the allocation in the loop would allow for garbaging collection to kick in preventing to overflow the heap. It rightly does so in Firefox, however in Chrome (tested on OSX) the snippet crashes the open tab after several iterations.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < 1024; ++i) {
            // Allocate a 16mb buffer
            var buffer = new Float32Array(1024*1024*4);

            // Try to explicitly mark it for free by either
            delete buffer;
            // or
            buffer = null;

            console.log(i);
    }
```

In itself this script it not all that useful. But I am trying to optimize my Javascript application in order for it to use less memory. Therefore I'd like your opinion. Is this a bug in Chrome? Do you know of any workarounds to explicitly call the garbage collection during code execution (in FF and IE they seem to exist)? Thanks!

---

Edit: There appears to exist a button on the Chrome Inspector called "Collect Garbage". It is the 7th button on the lower bar on the "Timeline" panel of the Inspector. Doesn't this signify that a way exist to call GC from Javascript? After all, aren't parts of the Inspector written in Javascript?

Comment: [The `delete` operator is not for variables, but for properties only](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/).

Comment: Interesting, Opera throws an `Unable to create ArrayBuffer of the given length` Error at iteration 210…

Comment: Interesting, at least Opera is smart enough to throw an exception so that the user can take action...

Comment: @StephanKristyn: Does that article really cover the OP's problem? I cant see any circular references, closures or DOM objects in his code, and the article does not mention Chrome or typed Arrays.

Comment: Right, I don't think to code above follows any of the patterns in the document, but thanks for the reference. Furthermore, it appears that if Chrome is given the time to collect garbage by using timeouts the memory is freed correctly: function f(i,dt) { console.log(i); if (i) { var x = new Float32Array(4*1024*1024); setTimeout("f(" + (i-1) + "," + dt + ")", dt); } }

Comment: Ah - you beat me to it. :)  If you write up your solution as an answer instead, then you can accept it.

Comment: I'm also a little curious what you could be doing in Javascript that requires that much memory...

Comment: It is a WebGL application that potentially requires several 100mb's of data

Comment: I created a JSFiddle with your original code. Link: http://jsfiddle.net/TzLxV/

Answer (score 2):

This is pure speculation, but I wonder whether the garbage collection is being postponed until the the current item on the run loop finishes executing.

If so, then perhaps it would work if you shaped it like this:

```
var i = 0;
function allocateArray() {
    var buffer = new Float32Array(1024*1024*4);
    if (++i < 1024) {
        setTimeout(allocateArray, 0); // Post the next call to the run loop
    }
}
allocateArray();
```

Comment: Hah yes as you noticed I was looking into something similar. However, using a timeout interval of 0 will not work. On my system it needs to be at least 5. It is not impossible to do my allocations this way, but I still have hopes for a better solution :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, calling GC doesn't work. You can explicitely call it e.g. in Chrome, but you need to have some debug option enabled, so that's not an option for the finished program.

Here's a Chromium bug about typed arrays not being garbage collected correctly.
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=232415

I personally have a program right now, where typed arrays are causing huge performance loss in Chrome and minor performance loss in other browsers.

I guess creating new typed arrays frequently should be avoided.(at the current time)

If someone knows more than me on this topic, i would really appreciate it.